# SPNEGO authorization : How can my browser succeed with no extra configuration, and my Java code fails?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, kerberos, spnego

All the examples I've seen for doing SPNEGO authorization in Java involve including configuration files like 'login.conf' and 'krb.conf', and yet Chrome succeeds without these files (after querying for name/pwd). I can also successfully query with curl.

Currently my code fails with "NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)" ...

```
Lookup<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
.register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory(skipPortAtKerberosDatabaseLookup))
.build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry).build();
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

Credentials defaultCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null), defaultCreds );
context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget,context);
String responseString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());

System.out.println(responseString);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote as a token of empathy. This is one of the most arcane corners of Java API. Post your `krb.conf` and `login.conf`, this should be relevant.

Comment: Lol, well I appreciate the empathy!  I have no krb.conf or login.conf, and I'm questioning why I need them at all.  This is a client's web service and all we have from them is a URL, a username, and a password.  These three pieces of information are enough to make it work in Chrome and Curl, so why not Java?  Been wrestling with this for days now.

Comment: Chrome and curl use the native C library and get access to stuff that the Java lib has to reimplement. If you're on Windows, there's a library that lets you access the same native APIs.

Comment: But then doesn't that imply there is some set of default values I can successfully use for the krb5.conf and login.conf?

Comment: try to google it out, those files are a mess. You have to specify encryption algorithms and stuff. It's been a long time for me and i don't remember anymore.

Comment: Ya I've been googling like crazy, testing, failing, and then came here to see if anyone could help.  I appreciate the replies!

Comment: AFAIK the **Windows** versions of curl, Chrome, Firefox etc. are compiled against the Microsoft **SSPI** libraries, and use the Windows-to-Active-Directory setup automatically. But Java uses **GSSAPI**. Therefore Java code makes it difficult to connect to Microsoft-compliant services, and the Microsoft stuff cannot connect to Java services.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Seriously? The last sentence is simply wrong.

Comment: @Michael-O Seriously, *AFAIK*. Prove me wrong, or be silent forever :-)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The implementation does not matter. The wire protocol is binary compatible. That is all what counts. Microsoft stuff can perfectly connect to the Java services.

Comment: @Michael-O So reality does not matter. All right. It's a matter of faith. End of discussion.